# The exit to or exit from a place?

Tags: prepositions, complements

New York Times article about restuarant employees blocking patrons from leaving the building:

> One of the arresting officers, Anthony Sengco, wrote in his criminal
>   complaint that he observed Dr. Pemberton, Mr. Baptiste and Mr. Debnam
>   blocking the exit to the restaurant and that the men had stated to him
>   that they were trying to prevent the women from leaving. The men deny
>   that they made any such statements to Mr. Sengco or that they were
>   trying to prevent the women from leaving.

Shouldn't this be **the exit *from* the restaurant**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some words, it is valid to phrase "the X's Y" as "the Y to the X" and that is what is happening here.

"blocking the exit to the restaurant" is intended as a shortened form of "blocking the exit [belonging] to the restaurant" and an alternative way to phrase "blocking the restaurant's exit", rather than as a counterpart to "blocking the exit from the restaurant".

The confusion arises because, in this case, "to" can refer to both movement and posession/ownership.

Consider "Hiding the key [belonging] to the door" as an alternative use with no movement-related interpretation.

Comment: Would whoever downvoted please explain so that I can learn from it?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you, but I voted you back up. I think your explanation makes perfect sense. Thank you)))